# Testing Spring Boot application with Spring Security using Spock

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spock

I am trying to do integration testing on Spring Boot application with Spring Security.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ApplicationSpec extends Specification{

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate

    def setup() {
        BasicAuthorizationInterceptor bai = new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor("username", "password")
        testRestTemplate.getRestTemplate().getInterceptors().add(bai)
    }
```

All the dependencies are there and TestRestTemplate gets injected. Problem is when I try to test POST endpoint. I get following error:

> Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not
>   found.

How do I get valid CSRF token and suply it to my TestRestTemplate?

Comment: You can disable csrf in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Comment: Don't want to do that.

Comment: You should first call GET and extract CSRF token `response.headers['x-csrf-token']` and then use the token sending in the header.